# Can't find Support Package in Android SDK Manager

Tags: android, sdk, package

I want to install support Compability Package but my SDK Manager doesn't see it. What should i fix?

Here is my screen:
[http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/20/clipboard01sj.jpg/](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/20/clipboard01sj.jpg)

But it should be like this:
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/209/clipboard02wm.jpg/

ADT version - 19. OS - Windows. I think that no problem with eclipse, because when i start SDK Manager without eclipse, thru Program Files I have the same situation.

Comment: have you tried updating your ADT?

Comment: Have you installed latest Android SDK tools/Android SDK platform-tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve problem by updating to the ADT version  20 . And Android Platform tools version 14.

Comment: My ADT Version ist 20 now - but I am not able to update the plattform tools to more than 12...

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide way way way way more information than that... what OS are you working with, what version of eclipse, which ADT revision, etc.

Honestly, I would just try a fresh install... trying to fix eclipse is a waste of time (in my experience at least). In your case, it seems like you are better off just starting from scratch.

Comment: ADT version - 19. OS - Windows. I think that no problem with eclipse, because when i start SDK Manager without eclipse, thru Program Files I have the same situation.

Comment: Well, ADT revision 20 is out... so maybe you can try updating? Help --> Check for updates, that is. Maybe that will help?