# Can't find Android Support Package

Tags: android

I have checked all these articles, and I still can't figure out why I can't find the Android Support Package/Library:

- [Cant' find Android Support package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12243030/cant-find-android-support-package)
- [Android Support package not present in SDK Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11244091/android-support-package-not-present-in-sdk-manager)
- [Can't find Support Package in Android SDK Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11349630/cant-find-support-package-in-android-sdk-manager)
- [Cannot find Support Package in Android SDK Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8038841/cannot-find-support-package-in-android-sdk-manager)

This is what the Android SDK Manager is showing me:
[image: Android SDK Manager Screenshot]

I have tried clearing the cache and reloading, but this is what I get.

Comment: While solving the same problem, it turned out that SDK Manager MUST be launched as standalone exe located in the SDK directory. If SDK Manager is opened from Eclipse it does only show already installed packages. I'm not sure if this is a bug or feature, and which specific part of entire software environment it belongs to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just try to reload once again.

if it doesn't work for you use this link to download the support package manually

http://venomvendor.blogspot.in/2012/03/android-sdk-extras-by-google-inc.html

extract the zip and copy it to directory

android-sdk\extras\support

this works for me

you can also try using Android Package Deployer to download API level manually

http://siddharthbarman.com/sidstream/index.php?r=software/apd

Comment: if you find a directory android-sdk\extras\compatibility rename it to android-sdk\extras\support and replace the file with new one

Comment: Today when I bring up the SDK manager, the loads a whole bunch of stuff from the web and shows me what I need. For some reason yesterday it was not even checking the web.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you didn't select "Show Obsolete Packages" in your SDK Manager.
It's in "Packages". Select it and reload.

[image]